# Mobile Geolocation requires two loads to be accurate

Tags: iphone, mobile, geolocation

**My Problem:**
It takes two page loads from my mobile browser (testing with iphone) to get an accurate result.  The first load will be half a mile or more off, and then the second load will be very close.

**My question:** 
What needs to be done to get the accurate location on the first load?

**Extra Info:**

I've read through http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/ and am taking advantage of watchPosition with the enableHighAccuracy.  Also I am using maximumAge:0 and timeout not set.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/

> If maximumAge is set to 0, the implementation must immediately attempt to acquire a new position object
>
> the default value used for the timeout attribute is Infinity

**My code is listed below**

```
// Try HTML5 geolocation
    if(navigator.geolocation) {

    // updated this with watchPosition rather than getCurrentPosition
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                         position.coords.longitude);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
        });

        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleNoGeolocation(true);
      },
    // enable high accuracy
    //  {maximumAge:100, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy: true}
            // 
                {maximumAge:0, enableHighAccuracy: true}
      );
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
      var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
      var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the solution to getting the most accurate geolocation possible.  You need to call clearWatch() after a given timeout. The timeout maybe time and or an event such as form click.

In my application I use a 5 second timeout and a click of a form element.

Here's all the useful code snippets.

Set the onclick

```
<select onclick="aFormClick()" id="location"
```

Set the timeout in the function that is the parent of the watchPosition function

```
setTimeout("stopWatchPosition()",5000);
```

Create a function to listen for the form click

```
function aFormClick(){
stopWatchPosition();
}
```

Create the function for calling clearnWatch()

```
function stopWatchPosition(){
if (clearWatchCalled == 0){
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
    clearWatchCalled++;
}
}
```

Make sure your watchPosition can be referenced by the ID

```
watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
```

Comment: Curious as to the increase in accuracy.  My single `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` call has variance of 100 metres.  Not good at all.

Answer (score 0):

The GPS radio is possibly not powered on at the time of the first page load.  To give the radio time to turn on, you might want to read a location to start the GPS, throw that first location result away, wait some number of second for the GPS radio to warm up and find enough satellites to get a good location fix, then read the location again in a timed async callback function.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll give that a shot and get back to you.

Comment: It didn't work, it just gave me the same coords each time.  I figured it out and posted the solution.  Thanks again for the response though.